# Swagger UI's URL path issue when deploy Net Core web project into server

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui

In my Net Core web project, I have a "Startup.cs" file which contain these scripts:

```
namespace HangfireProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
        {
            public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context) => true;
        }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

            services.AddHangfire
            (x => x.UseSqlServerStorage
                (
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection")
                )
            );

            services.AddHangfireServer();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HangfireProject", Version = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_VERSION") ?? "v1" });
            });

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddHealthChecks()
                    .AddCheck("Version", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_VERSION") ?? "v1"))
                    .AddSqlServer(
                                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"),
                                    healthQuery: "SELECT 1;",
                                    name: "HangfireConnection",
                                    failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded,
                                    tags: new string[] { "SqlServer", "HangfireConnection" }
                                 );
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var pathBase = Configuration["API_PATH_BASE"] ?? "";

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathBase))
            {
                app.UsePathBase($"/{pathBase.TrimStart('/')}");
            }

            if(env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();

                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{pathBase}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"HangfireProject {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_VERSION") ?? "v1"}");
                    c.RoutePrefix = "hangfire/swagger";
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHangfireDashboard($"{pathBase}/hangfiredashboard", new DashboardOptions()
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() },
                IgnoreAntiforgeryToken = true
            });

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.UseHealthChecks($"{pathBase}/infra/selfcheck", new HealthCheckOptions
            {
                Predicate = _ => true,
                ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse,

                ResultStatusCodes =
                {
                    [HealthStatus.Healthy] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Degraded] = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
                    [HealthStatus.Unhealthy] = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                },

                AllowCachingResponses = true,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this web project on local, I am able to access the Swagger UI normally using this URL
**"https://localhost:32774/hangfire/swagger"**

But when I execute this web project on server, I am unable to access the Swagger UI using this URL
**"https://myproject.com/hangfire/swagger"**
as the error 404 occurs

**--------------------**

Can someone please help me analyze about the cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?

Thank you in advance.

**--------------------**

**PS:**
This issue seems to specifically affect the "Swagger UI" only as I am still able to access the "HangFire UI" and "HealthCheck UI" through these URLs **"https://myproject.com/hangfire/hangfiredashboard"** and **"https://myproject.com/hangfire/infra/selfcheck"** normally